# Order by with and without Limit clause uses different index

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

Can someone explain why the optimizer chooses different indexes if Limit is used?

MariaDB >

```
EXPLAIN SELECT dms_meta.docid 
FROM dms_meta 
WHERE (dms_meta.metid = 3 and dms_meta.value = '2015-10-01') 
ORDER BY dms_meta.docid ASC limit 25;

+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | dms_meta | index | indx_metaid   | indx_docid | 8       | NULL | 889  | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB >

```
EXPLAIN SELECT dms_meta.docid 
FROM dms_meta 
WHERE (dms_meta.metid = 3 and dms_meta.value = '2015-10-01') 
ORDER BY dms_meta.docid ASC;

+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                       |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | dms_meta | ref  | indx_metaid   | indx_metaid | 4       | const | 121880 | Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+--------+-----------------------------+
```

1 row in set (0.000 sec)

The first query completes in 0.5 second, whereas the second one in more than 6 seconds. I am using
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.11.4-MariaDB

Oddly enough on on MySql 5.0.95 both queries choose the same index and complete in less than a second.

Any suggections?

Selecting different indexes with Limit in select makses huge impact on performance, but I need the engine to make the proper selection everytime

Comment: please edit your question to show output of `show create table dms_meta.docid`, thanks

Comment: IMO embrace [index hints](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/index-hints-how-to-force-query-plans/).  if you know what index you want to use, tell the query that.

Comment: [ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) shows execution measure as well. 11.0+ (no LTS version as of today) has improved optimizer so might be benefit here.

Answer (score 0):

No, I can't completely explain the choice.  But here is some hand-waving.  Statistics are gathered on the selectivity of the columns mentioned in the possible indexes and the "best" one is picked.  It may not be the best when the query actually runs.

Your query would run fun much faster with

```
INDEX(metid, value, docid)
```

If `value` is `TEXT`, then Ugh!  This smells like an Entity-Attribute-Value schema, which has all sorts of problems.  For that, here is what I recommend:  [*Entity-Attribute-Value*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav) and here is a plugin that helps WordPress:  [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I still don't know why in Mysql 5.0.95 the same index (the one in the where condition) is used with or without the Limit clause. The app that uses the database in question was migrated from old MySql server to the new MariaDB engine and performance dropped a lot.

Comment: @AngelA - Way back in 5.0 (released about 14 years ago), the Optimizer was much simpler -- it ignored the `LIMIT` and was often wrong in doing so.  So they eventually "improved" it to take `LIMIT` into account -- but that sometimes makes it worse.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `LIMIT 25`, the best performance can be achieved by iterating through the index for the `ORDER BY` column, testing the `WHERE` condition on each row and stopping when 25 matches are found.

Without the limit, it can do better by using the index that filters on one of the columns in the `WHERE` clause. This reduces the total number of rows that have to be sorted by `ORDER BY` after everything is fetched.

Comment: (Hmmm...  I almost submitted my answer twice, too.  Did Stackoverflow change something for the worse?)

Comment: They had an incident a earlier today. https://www.stackstatus.net/incidents/b6cf83c3-9af8-4b0d-8f49-9657b1650028

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - it completely makes sense, however in Mysql 5.0.95 the same index (the one in the where condition) is used with or without the Limit clause. Any idea why?

Comment: @AngelA MySQL's query optimizer can be quite inscrutible. And 5.0 is so old that I don't think it's worth speculating -- they presumably hadn't yet implemented this optimization.